# Does $\sqsubset$ have any special meaning?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

What is the meaning of $\sqsubset$ and $\sqsubseteq$? Does it have any special meaning, or is it just an alternative to writing $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ respectively (for proper subsets and subsets)?

I have been looking for an explanation everywhere, but so far I could not find it. This may have to do with the fact that I am not even sure what this symbol is called (makes it difficult to search for it), but I have tried several things (like searching for $\sqsubset$ on this site), and nothing came up, other than lists of mathematical symbols for LaTeX without any explanation.

I have seen it used in papers (e.g., http://www.cril.univ-artois.fr/~marquis/everaere-konieczny-marquis-ecai10.pdf on page 4, footnote 5), but never explained. I am starting to think that $\sqsubset$ and $\sqsubseteq$ are equivalent to $\subset$ and $\subseteq$. However, sometimes there are subtle differences, so I want to be certain about this. I want to be sure that I understand the intended meaning when reading future papers, to avoid any misunderstandings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The paper you linked seems to define the symbol as inclusion of profiles. The definition is in the Preliminaries section at the end of the fourth paragraph.

Comment: From the context, it is clear that this is simply the subset symbol- possibly in an unfortunate typeface!

Comment: No it seems to be a little stronger. Since the order of the $K$ and $K'$ elements matters.

Comment: So, if I understand it correctly, $E \sqsubseteq E'$ iff $E = E'$, or $E$ is contained in $E'$ such that the first element to some element in $E'$ is equal to $E$ (without leaving any "gaps").

It is also about vectors rather than sets, as I understand it.

Comment: @Jochem I haven't read the entire paper but it seems to be something along those lines. But at least you have a definition now.

Comment: Yes. I do. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no universally accepted meaning for $\sqsubset$ or $\sqsubseteq$. If you see it in a book or article, it will have to be defined by the author in-context.

In general, there are a ton of symbols available in LaTeX (e.g. $\precsim$, $\oplus$, $\curlyvee$) that don't have well-agreed-upon meanings. These are there so that authors have access to plenty of characters to define their own operators.

Comment: $\sqsubset$, $\sqsubseteq$, sqsuperset, and sqsuperseteq (the "reverse" relations) are labeled *square image of*, *square image of or equal to*, *square original of*, and *square original of or equal to* respectively. Finding accessible definitions for these terms via search engine is proving difficult and likely for good reason!

Answer (score 4):

> The square subset symbol is sometimes used to indicate a prefix, so that $x \sqsubseteq y$ denotes that $x$ is a prefix of $y$. This defines a binary relation on strings, called the **[prefix relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_operations#Prefixes)**, which is a particular kind of **[prefix order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_order)**.

This interpretation seems to make sense for the example you cited:

> $(E_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ satisfies $\forall i \in \mathbb{N}, E_i \sqsubseteq E_{i+1}$

meaning $E_i$ is a prefix of $E_{i+1}$.

Comment: This is also consistent with the usage of  ⊏ or ⊑  in  "Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen, Leiserson, Revist, and Stein.

Comment: Cormen et. al is also what brought me here.  They use $\sqsubset$ and $\sqsupset$ to refer to string prefix and suffix relationships respectively.  Ie  "aab" $\sqsubset$ "aabcde"  and "cde" $\sqsupset$ "aabcde"

Comment: See their definition on pg 986 of the third edition.