# Can someone help me identify this math symbol and its meaning?

Tags: formal-languages

From my university notes:

> **Comment to slide 9**
>
> By virtue of the result shown in this slide, we can talk about *the* least element of a set $D$, if one exists, and we denote it with $\perp$, pronounced "bottom". As an example, given the set $S=\{1,2,3\}$, the pair $(\mathcal{P}(S),\subseteq)$ (where $\mathcal{P}(S)$ denotes the power set of $S$) is a poset and the empty set is its bottom.
>
> Having introduced an ordering on the partial functions, we can now summarize the require-ments for $\mathrm{FIX}\,F$:
>
> - $\mathrm{FIX}\,F$ is a fixed point of $F$, that is $F(\mathrm{FIX}\,F)=\mathrm{FIX}\,F$ and
> - $\mathrm{FIX}\,F$ is a least fixed point of $F$, that is if $Fg=g$ then $\mathrm{FIX}\,\color{red}{F\sqsubseteq g}$.
>
> The next task is to ensure that all functionals $F$ that may arise in ${\tt While}$ do indeed have least fixed points.

There is this symbol which looks like a square version of an inclusion symbol but there is also an actual inclusion symbol in this same it of text. Here is another example of it's usage:
**Fixed point theory**

> **Definition** A *partially ordered set* is a pair $(D,\sqsubseteq_D)$, where $D$ is a set and $\sqsubseteq_D$ is a reflexive, transitive, anti-symmetric relation on $D$.
>
> **Example** Defined the **ordering** $\sqsubseteq$ on partial functions of $\mathbf{State}\hookrightarrow\mathbf{State}$:
> $$g_1\sqsubseteq g_2\ \text{whenever}$$
> $$\text{if}\ g_1s=s'\ \text{then}\ g_2s=s'\ \text{for all choices of}\ s\ \text{and}\ s'$$
> then $(\mathbf{State}\hookrightarrow\mathbf{State},\sqsubseteq)$ is a **poset**.

As you can see the symbol can also contain a subscript (in this case $D$). What does this symbol mean? when is is used and what does the subscript stand for?

Both of these examples are in context to Denotational semantics. I tried to google the meaning but couldn't find anything. copy-pasting the symbol in the search bar resulted in pasting a `v` character

Comment: Surely the specific symbol is defined in the "Example"?

Comment: It is used as symbol for [Partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set), as an alternative to the usual $\le$

Comment: no it isn't. the example in slide 9 doesn't define it and the second image is slide 8 and it isn't defined before that either...

Comment: The sub $D$ is just to remind you that it's a partial order on $D$. (I think the author is being too casuall.)

Comment: You are too quick to reject @MauroALLEGRANZA 's comment.

Comment: We read: "Having introduced an ordering on the partial function..." that means that we can meaningfully write $f \le g$ between partial functions.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That's helpful, could you write it as an answer

Comment: @ancientmathematician we posted at the same moment, that comment was in response to your first comment...

Comment: Oh, in that case you are wrong.

Comment: @ancientmathematician could you explain how in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) identifies it as `\sqsubseteq`. As discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569400/does-sqsubset-have-any-special-meaning), its meaning is highly context-dependent. But @MauroALLEGRANZA has identified the meaning applicable here.

Answer (score 1):

In this CS context, I think $\sqsubseteq$ would be called the refinement relation (see, for example Morgan's [*Programming from Specifications*](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/publications/books/PfS/)). The subscript $D$ is just a reminder of the set $\sqsubseteq$ is defined on. Here one partial function $g_1$ is refined by another function $g_2$,  if they agree wherever $g_1$ is defined (allowing for the possibility that the domain of $g_2$ strictly includes $g_1$, so that $g_2$ is "more defined" than $g_1$). Typically refinement is about resolving indeterminacy (a.k.a., strengthening the post-condition) and expanding the domain of definition (a.k.a., weakening the pre-condition). Here the relations being refined are deterministic (i.e., partial functions), so only weakening the pre-condition applies.